# How to structure Maven jars for full source building

Tags: maven

We have a monorepo and now try to get Maven to compile our various Java programs.

An example directory tree might look like:

```
pom.xml
src/main/java/com/company
| program12
  | Main.java
  | pom.xml
| mod1
  | Sweet.java
  | pom.xml
| mod2
  | Sour.java
  | pom.xml
| program2
  | Main.java
  | pom.xml
```

In both `mod1` and `mod2` I can *package* the jars just fine.
I now would like for e.g. `program12` to build and include `mod1` and `mod2` and `program2` to build and include only `mod2`.

Therefor I added the necessary dependencies to both `pom.xml`s. Calling `mvn package` in `program12` and `program2` complains that the modules cannot be found in remote repos.

How can I tell Maven to not bother with remote repos and use the local Modules?

I tried adding `modules` to the root `pom.xml` but that did not change the behavior.
There is probably a part of the logic of Maven I have not yet understood. Would be nice if someone could clear that up.

Comment: Simple answer to this. If you have different programs you should make separate modules and each modules should correctly contain the directory layout https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html ...If you correctly define each module with the correct structure etc. you can define dependencies between your modules ....

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding is the following:

To resolve module dependencies, you need to build the project from the root POM, i.e. go to the POM that contains the modules and run something like `mvn clean package` there. It will then build the modules in the correct order and resolve dependencies between them.

If you only want build some modules, you can use parameters like `-pl` and `-am`.

Comment: I think my mental model was something more straightforward - similar to Go modules or Rust crates.

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Go or Rust. If you want to, you can also structure the project into different levels, each with a root POM.

Comment: What actually helped me is both the comment from @khmarbaise as well as the `-pl` `-am` options.